# Send email on every change of service status

Tags: cron, email

I am running a Debian server and i have setup mailutils to send an email from command line from `root@localhost` to an external email.

I would like to slightly modify it, so it can send emails on every service change. eg

- ssh new logins
- iptables restart
- fail2ban restart
- system reboot
- asterisk restart
- etc

if possible, together with the system information such as CPU, RAM, HDD status.

Comment: There are more monitoring solutions out there than you can evaluate in an year.  They can monitor every aspect of your system that you can possibly care about, then send you notifications in any formats imaginable, and make colourful graphs.  Don't waste your time re-inventing this particular wheel.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. could you name the monitoring solutions please? the system is very small in cpu/ram and i do not want to overload it.

Comment: `nagios`, `cacti`, `collectd`, `munin`, `monit` are the first that come to mind.  Please consider doing your own research for more.